# Delimit file path into multiple database columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, etl

I am trying to delimit a file path and populate it into multiple database columns.

So if the string were `C:\Engineering\Structural\CAD\Baghouse.dwg` then it would populate 8 database columns, 5 with values and 3 with "".

```
DIR01   |   C:  
DIR02   |   Engineering  
DIR03   |   Structural  
DIR04   |   CAD  
DIR05   |   Baghouse.dwg  
DIR06   |     
DIR07   |     
DIR08   |
```

I can easily delimit the file path using `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`, and when I debug and look in the `Locals` box the array looks perfect.

What I can't figure out is how to access each element of the array and put them into separate columns.

```
    private void cmdDelimitFilePath_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SqlCmd;
        string ScannedPath = String.Empty;
        string DIR01 = String.Empty;
        string DIR02 = String.Empty;
        string DIR03 = String.Empty;
        string DIR04 = String.Empty;
        string DIR05 = String.Empty;
        string DIR06 = String.Empty;
        string DIR07 = String.Empty;
        string DIR08 = String.Empty;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("DirectoryAnalysis");

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        try
        {
            ConnStrBuilder.DataSource = txtServer.Text;
            ConnStrBuilder.InitialCatalog = txtSourceSchema.Text;
            ConnStrBuilder.Password = txtPassword.Text;
            ConnStrBuilder.UserID = txtUser.Text;

            //this connects to the database and creates the new fields
            using (DbConnection connexx = new SqlConnection(ConnStrBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                connexx.Open();
                using (DbCommand command = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE [DirectoryAnalysis] ADD [DIR01] varchar(100), [DIR02] varchar(100), [DIR03] varchar(100), [DIR04] varchar(100), [DIR05] varchar(100), [DIR06] varchar(100), [DIR07] varchar(100), [DIR08] varchar(100)"))
                {
                    command.Connection = connexx;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            // this connects to the database and populates the new fields
            using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStrBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                Conn.Open();
                SqlCmd = "SELECT [DA_Id], [ScannedPath], [DIR01], [DIR02], [DIR03], [DIR04], [DIR05], [DIR06], [DIR07], [DIR08] FROM [DirectoryAnalysis]";

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCmd, Conn))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        ScannedPath = Convert.ToString(dr["ScannedPath"]);

                        //This returns each individual folder in the directories array.
                        string[] directories = ScannedPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

                        //You can get the number of folders returned like this:
                        int folderCount = directories.Length;

                        // everything works perfectly up to here... 
                        foreach (string part in directories)
                        {
                            // how to access elements of the array?

                            //this is as close as I have been...
                            DIR01 = Convert.ToString(part[0]);
                            dr["DIR01"] = DIR01;
                            DIR02 = Convert.ToString(part[1]);
                            dr["DIR02"] = DIR02;
                            DIR03 = Convert.ToString(part[2]);
                            dr["DIR03"] = DIR03;

                            // and repeat through 8 if this would work
                        }
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("DirectoryAnalysis has been updated.", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF i understand correctly, the problem is the following:

You need access to all the elements of the array "directories" at the same time. However, you LOSE it by doing:

foreach (string part in directories)

because "part" is the current element, and it's difficult(ish) to take the previous n elements.

Hence, i think the fix is:

Stop using the foreach loop and access each element of the array like this:

dir1 = directories[0]
dir2 = directories[1]

and so on.

Like this, you can also use them directly in your sql insert statement.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
string[] StrArr = filePath.Split('\');
```

.

```
for (int i = 0; i < StrArr.length - 1; i++)
{
    //Run this SQL command:
    String.Format("UPDATE [table] (DIR{0}) VALUES ({1})", i + 1, StrArr[i])
}
```

1. Split string to Array
2. loop through array with a for loop
3. Update database with the values